# How to make a Table using Json with images on top

Tags: json, angular, image

I don't know how to put this in order to look the same table, I understand I need to code in base64 the images, but I don't know how to put those images in the json in order to shown the same way.

```
 <div class="pt-3">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="https://d1yjjnpx0p53s8.cloudfront.net/styles/logo-thumbnail/s3/062013/huawei_0.jpg"
          width="96" height="48"></td>
        <td><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg/170px-Apple_logo_black.svg.png" width="96"
          height="48"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <table>ILX A-SPEC 4P L4 2.4L QC NAVI R18 AUT 5 OCUP</table>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><button mat-button>
          <mat-icon>check_box_outline_blank</mat-icon>
        </button></td>
        <td><button mat-button>
          <mat-icon>check_box_outline_blank</mat-icon>
        </button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <table>ILX A-SPEC 4P L4 2.4L QC</table>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><button mat-button>
          <mat-icon>check_box_outline_blank</mat-icon>
        </button></td>
        <td><button mat-button>
          <mat-icon>check_box_outline_blank</mat-icon>
        </button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
```

Comment: There is no json in the question, that is HTML.

Comment: I thought you would understand me better if I set the example in HTML